# Headless Magento

Tags: best-practice, webapi, headless

Please let me know the best practices to be followed while creating an **e-commerce solution** which uses the **headless approach**.

Whether Magento or frontend-side need to implement custom business logic if there is a need to combine responses of various web API requests to create the presentation layer

Comment: Latest magento release(2.3) supporting graphql also. for headless api call you need to use that